# vuejs2 vuex actions emit data to component

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I'm making some async vuex action which I called from component, and then that action will store something on localforage, so what I want is to detect that change in localforage from component, which method should I use?

1. emit something from vuex actions to component (how?)
2. detect localforage change in component (how?)

here's my vuex actions:

```js
const actions = {

  someFunction(){
    var data=[]
    for (let index = 1; index < max; index++) {
      someAsyncFunction.then(function(value) {
        if(value === null){
          data.push(value)
          localforage.setItem('smth', data)
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Note: I don't want to use vuex state management

Comment: _"I don't want to use vuex state management"_... then why even use Vuex?

Comment: forgive me but I'm new in vue, I do it because I need the action? because the async function will keep running even if the route changing.

Comment: Ideally, you should also save the data in your state along with setting it in browser storage. This is because depending on the storage configured, setting an item can be either sync or async which would lead to blocking UI in either case. I'd suggest store your data in the state as well and fetch persisting data on app load. If not, you'd have to listen to `storage` event in your component.

Comment: @slumbergeist Thanks for the suggestions, I realise that best practice would be to save it to state and listen to it. But I still want to know the alternative, what do you mean by listen to storage? Do I use setinterval to watch it?

Comment: If your forage is configured for localStorage then you can listen for [storage event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event). But, In case of `indexDb`, you'd have to wait for the promise to be resolved. So, you might have to write your action such that it can recieve a function as its argument, which you'd hv to execute once your indexDB set resolves.